# How does NSMonthCalendarUnit and NSYearCalendarUnit behave exactly when used with UILocalNotification repeatInterval?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, repeat

How does NSMonthCalendarUnit behave exactly related to UILocalNotification repeatInterval ?

Find same day next month ?

or

Find the date for 30 days later ?

For example:
if i create a UILocalNotification with date:27/02/2015 and repeatInterval:NSMonthCalendarUnit when will be the next notification ? Do not mind whether February is 27 or 28. Just consider it is always 28. It is not the real question.

Will repetition be on 27/03/2015 or 29/03/2015 ?

Same question also applies for NSYearCalendarUnit. Is it just a addition of 365 days or does it mean same day, same month of next year (27/03/2016) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would post this as an edit, but it's a bit long.

I imagine this does is based on the unit. For instance, if you create a uilocalnotification with date Feb 2, 2015 and give it an NSMonthCalendarUnit, it will call it again at every month interval for the same date.

Broken down into components Feb 2 2015 is NSDayCalendarUnit=2, NSMonthCalendarUnit=2 NSYearCalendarUnit=2015. So, the notification will be called whenever NSDayCalendarUnit=2 and NSYearCalendarUnit=2015 for any NSMonthCalendarUnit. (so if you did a leap-year date at the end of the month, like jan 30, and it was a leap year month in february, it wouldn't get called.) So, this would have the same day and year for ever NSMonthCalendarUnit. The same goes for year, except for years.

It would not make much sense for this to be an addition of days. Imagine setting the NSMonth interval for a date on the first and having it be returned on the 31st of the same month, that wouldn't be a very practical API.